# Mongoose nested populate second level

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        text: { type: String, required: true },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
        viewCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        imageUrl: String,
        comments: [
            {
                text: String,
                user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
                createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
            },
        ],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

I tried these methods, but not successfully:

```
.populate(comments.user)


.populate({
   path: 'comments',
   populate: {
       path: 'user'
   }
})
```

Can you help me to populate comments > user?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
.populate('comments.user')
```